# C# Datagridview , first column (ID) must be primary key without using database, how to setup it?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a small problem, don't know how to setup primary key for first column (ID)?
Can somebody help?

This is my code:

```cs
Datatable tabela;

private void Admin_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tabela = new DataTable();
    //this column should be primary key
    tabela.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
    tabela.Columns.Add("Naziv", typeof(string));
    tabela.Columns.Add("Zanr", typeof(string));
    tabela.Columns.Add("Duzina", typeof(int));
    tabela.Columns.Add("Granica godina: ", typeof(int));
    dataGridView1.DataSource = tabela;
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem with setting up an id? To find a unique one? If so a common solution is to use a Guid.

Comment: I dont know how to setup id using code without database , how I can use that GUID for this ?

Comment: Please specify more what do you need the data for? is it going to be saved in the db? or is it just to be shown on the data grid? I know you wrote without db! but does it means that you will not save this data in the db?

Comment: Data should be saved to the text file

Comment: `tabela.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(int)) { AutoIncrement = true, AutoIncrementSeed = 1, AutoIncrementStep = 1, Unique = true });`

Answer (score 0):

Use GIUD as a string if you want like this:

```
string guid = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
```

Even thought the possibility of having a duplicate GIUD is negligible, but in your case, you are having a "figurative" Id which means that you would not know IF you ever had a duplicate Id, I should mention that using a giud for an id instead of a number is a wast of memory and it's inefficient in these cases, but I don't know what's your point.

PS: if you want a number and nothing else, use a random numbers generatore, but the possibility to get a duplicate ID will increase inversely with respect to the range of numbers you specify:

```
Random r = new Random();
r.Next(start_range, end_range);
```